# Android - Show Sound Notification

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity

I am new to android programming. What I have achieved is that I have set up a Android Studio App and made it work correctly with your help and plays audio files. But I can't figure out how to make it colored the right way. I want it to be like the sound notifications by YouTube, Spotify and Amazon Musik. The all look exactly the same so I think it's something built in but I can't find out what and how to set it up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put up a screenshot for above ?

Comment: Read here: https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/android-custom-notification-for-music-player-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Intent with custom action name like this

```
  Intent switchIntent = new Intent("com.example.app.ACTION_PLAY");
```

Then, register the `PendingIntent` `Broadcast` receiver

```
  PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, switchIntent, 0);
```

Then, set a `onClick` for the play control , do similar custom action for other controls if required.

```
  notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn_play_pause_in_notification, pendingSwitchIntent);
```

Next,Register the custom action in `AudioPlayerBroadcastReceiver` like this

```
   <receiver android:name="com.example.app.AudioPlayerBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.app.ACTION_PLAY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Finally, when play is clicked on `Notification` `RemoteViews` layout, you will receive the `play action` by the `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class AudioPlayerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();

    if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("com.example.app.ACTION_PLAY")){
        // do your stuff to play action;
    }
   }
}
```

You can also set the `Custom  Action` through `Intent filter`  from code for the registered `Broadcast receiver`  like this

```
    // instance of custom broadcast receiver
    CustomReceiver broadcastReceiver = new CustomReceiver();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    // set the custom action
    intentFilter.addAction("com.example.app.ACTION_PLAY");
    // register the receiver
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```